# delete session files older than one day, not working

Tags: magento2, cron, session

I would like to clean session files older than one day.

I clean with cron with this

```
find /path/to/magento/var/session/ -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

and my cron setting is to run once a day, so

```
0 0 * * *
```

But it seems to be not working correct.
As of now (9:07 am 16 July 2017), oldest session file's last modified time/date is 20:03 14 July.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting based on the last modified time, use the creation time with `-ctime` also check your find command the following works for me

```
find magento/var/session/sess* -type f -ctime +1 -exec rm -- {} \;
```

Comment: I tried your method, still strange. As of now (18 July 2017 8:57 am),  the oldest session file's last modified date is 16 July 22:00)

Comment: Strange, I take it your user has permission to delete the files? I would actually recommend you move your sessions to a redis cache server then you never have to worry about deleting them...

Comment: seems to be cron worked at some point and now (19 July 2017 12:04 pm), the oldest session file's last modified date is 18 July 14:56). So does this mean cron is not running according to the time set?